# What is the difference between body and body-params in compojure-api?

Tags: clojure, swagger, plumatic-schema, compojure-api

In compojure-api I noticed this two ways of specifying the API of a resource:

```
(POST* "/register" []
    :body [user UserRegistration]
    (ok)))
```

and

```
(POST* "/register" []
    :body-params [username :- String,
                  password :- String]
    (ok)))
```

What are the difference between these two? What are the implications of using one vs the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference is in how the params are specified (and destructured thereafter):

[`body`](https://github.com/metosin/compojure-api/blob/9e2bd39a11b4064cc277fe33b79db3a89cb062d2/src/compojure/api/meta.clj#L187-L194):

> reads body-params into a enhanced `let`. First parameter is the `let`
>   symbol, second is the Schema to `coerced!` against.
>
> Example:
>   `:body [user User]`

[`body-params`](https://github.com/metosin/compojure-api/blob/9e2bd39a11b4064cc277fe33b79db3a89cb062d2/src/compojure/api/meta.clj#L214-L220):

> restructures body-params with plumbing `letk` notation.
>
> Example: `:body-params [id :- Long name :- String]`

Depending on the situation you might prefer one or the other. In both cases the params (`user` in first case, `id` and `name` in the second) will be in scope for the body.